# How to deactivate firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

How can I completly deactivate firebug without uninstalling it?

I installed firebug because there are some cool extensions like "Firepath" so you can read out the Xpath. However, there are also some missing features which are included in the normal dev console, e.g. manipulating the CSS of the currently selected element.

So to use these features I have to switch back to the normal developer console. However, firebug is still active after deactivating the addon.

[image]

Still appears in the menu at the top:
[image]

And if I press **F12** then Firebug opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, deactivating an extension within the Add-on Manager, like you did, completely deactivates it.

When it's still activated, it's a bug and you should [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Toolkit&component=Add-ons%20Manager).

Having said that, note that [Firebug's development is discontinued](https://getfirebug.com/) and [it will not work anymore once multi-process Firefox is enabled](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/). Furthermore, Mozilla [plans to stop supporting extensions that are not based on the WebExtension framework starting from Firefox 57](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/), which is released in November 2017. At latest at that point in time Firebug (as well as most existing Firefox extensions) definitely stops working.

Regarding the XPath features, there are [several](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963933) [feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=987877) [requests](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1032855) filed for the DevTools already asking to implement advanced XPath support.